# Detecting Misaligned Link in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I recently completed an initial port of a very large MFC/C++ application from Visual C++ 6 to VS 2010.  This project includes about 25 custom DLL modules.  After most compilation problems were solved, I would repeatedly encountered a runtime exception in one of the DLL modules when one of these related DLL methods was called.  Running in the debugger was no help because I just got nonsense right after the exception: corrupted CStrings that were previously accessable right before the damaging call and the like.  Same effect in VS 2008.  The debugger and call stack was just lost. (This should have been a clue)

After a few weeks of head scratching and further debugging, I *finally* did more examination of the source code for several of the DLLs and discovered that about 20 of the header files turned on/off byte alignment as follows:

```
#pragma pack(push,1) 

...
Some byte aligned structures
...
#pragma pack(pop,1)
```

Well after reading the MSDN documentation again I realized they had made a mistake and that they should have made the second pragma to be `#pragma pack(pop)` to revert to the previous packing alignment.  They were in fact leaving byte-aligned packing on.

This byte misalignment in the DLL caused hell to break loose when some the DLL functions got called.  You can't imagine the relief when this magically fixed the problem.

Now to my questions:

1. Why didn't this damage the link in the older VC++ 6 build?  I can
   only assume the old compiler had a 'feature' to prevent this from
   being a problem in a binary, static or dynamic.
2. Is there a way to detect this via a compiler switch or another means.  This was a really nasty bug to find and I wasted way too
   much time finding it!

Thanks for any advice ya'll may be able to provide.